# Segmentation Fault when returning integer

Tags: c, arrays, struct, segmentation-fault, return-value

I recently joined Stackoverflow community because I had to ask this question. I've been searching for possible explanations and solutions on the website but so far nothing enlightened me as I wanted. My error is probably caused by a very specific line of code. I'm trying to create a function that reads an array of struct votes, (struct contains integer member number, char *category, char *nominee) and copies all the votes that contain the same number and category to another array of struct. Basically to show all the repeated votes.

```
typedef struct
{ 
  int member;
  char *categ;
  char *nom;
}Vote

Vote vote(int member, char *categ, char *nom)
{
  Vote result;
  result.member = member;
  result.categ = categ;
  result.nom = nom;
  return result;
}

int votes_count(Vote *v, int n, Vote *v1) 
{
    int result = 0;
    int *index = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1000);
    int a = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
     for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
     {
       if (a == 0 && v[i].member == v[j].member && strcmp(v[i].categ, v[j].categ) == 0)
       {
          v1[result++] = vote(v[j].member, str_dup(v[j].categ), str_dup(v[j].nom)); 
          index[a++] = j;
       }
        for (int b = 0; b < a; ++b)
        {
          if( a > 0 && v[i].member == v[j].member && strcmp(v[i].categ, v[j].categ) == 0 && j != index[b])
          {
            v1[result++] = voto(v[j].member, str_dup(v[j].categ), str_dup(v[j].nom));
            index[a++] = j; 
          }
        }       
      }
    }
    return result;
 }
```

Afterwads, it returns the number of elements of new array that contains all repetitions. I want to use an array of ints to save all line indexes so that the function doesn't read and copy the lines it already accounted.
Sorry if the code is hard to understand, if needed I can edit to be more understandable. Thanks for any answears.
P.S: I'm portuguese, sorry in advance for grammar mistakes

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: 1) You don't use the index array, you only write to it.(and never free it) 1a) on second view, you *do* use it (please avoid long lines...) 2) if your only intention is to harvest the duplicates, you only need to compare to the elements that came before an element..

Comment: @ArndtJonasson I did. it gives me: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strcmp_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse2-unaligned.S:31
31 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse2-unaligned.S: File or missing directory

Answer (score 0):

- if your only intention is to harvest the duplicates, you only need to compare to the elements that came *before* an element
- you don't need the `index[]` array

For simplicity, I used two integer arrays, you should change them to your struct arrays, also change the compare function.

---

```
unsigned fetchdups(int orig[], int dups[], unsigned count)
{
unsigned this, that, ndup=0;

for (this=1; this<count; this++){
        for (that=0; that<this; that++){
                /* change this to your compare() */
                if(orig[that] == orig[this]) break;
                }
        if (this == that) continue; /* no duplicate */
        dups[ndup++] = this;
        }
return ndup;
}
```

Comment: I probably didn't explain myself properly, i don't want to just harvest the duplicates, I want every single vote that has the same Member number and Category. The purpose of the algorithm is to find if any member voted on the same category more than once to different nominees, for instance: 1) 100, Best actor, John 2)220, Best music, Kendrick 3)100, Best actor, Penelope. -- 
In this case the answer should be '2' because there's 2 instances with the same number and category.

Sorry for long lines

Comment: Please rephrase: You want the *distinct set* of elements that occur more than once?

Comment: if there's more than one element with the same number and category, both elements need to be copied to second array. Meaning: all elements with same number and category will be accounted and copied